# Manage Python exception breakpoints

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm trying to use the 'Manage Python Exception Breakpoints' feature in PyDev.

Debugging the following script after selecting run -> 'Manage Python Exception Breakpoints' and selecting all exceptions.

```
print 1
print 2
assert(False)
print 3
```

nothing happens and I just get an exception as normal.

EDIT:-

It seems the problem is with matplotlib. the following script exhibits the problem I saw previously.  pydev breaks somewehere in pylab and I can't step out to my script.

```
import pylab as pyp

print 1
print 2
assert(False)
print 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked it here and it seems to work properly for me... Are you running in debug mode? ( there are steps on how to run in debug mode at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html )

Comment: yes seems to be working today. before when I had 'suspend on caught exceptions' ticked the script was stopping at all sorts of places in pydev, and not even reaching my script.  At least that is what I remember.  some kind of friday error I think perhaps... still it's working for me now.