# Inspect variables after exception in Python/Pydev/Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, exception, pydev

Can I inspect variables on the stack after there is an uncaught exception in Python/Pydev/Eclipse? I'd like to go back in stack levels and see the local variables.

I suppose there are ways to hack this in Python, but is there an easy way in Eclipse?

Comment: It looks like this has come up before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940342/manage-python-exception-breakpoints, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455552/break-on-exception-in-pydev, etc.  Make sure you have PyDev 2.2 or later!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to 'hack' this into python, you just use ipython:

```
ipython yourscript.py --pdb
```

whenever 'yourscript.py' crashes, you'll land in the ipython debugger on the spot where the exception was raised. From there you can move the stack up and down and inspect the variables etc. as needed. Thanks to ipython you'll even have tab-completion.

Sure enough it's not Eclipse but it straightforward and incredibly useful when developing in Python.